# Reference related resources in API Post method

Tags: json, api, asp.net-core, api-design

I am creating an API's endpoint that creates a post:

```
POST > /posts
```

Each post can have up to one Category and multiple Tags.

When creating a post I need to reference its Category and Tags if any:

1. To reference the Category usually I send the CategoryId;
2. To reference the Tags usually I send Tags names because some of them might be new.

So my Json would be something like:

```
{
  "title": "Some title",
  "content": "Some content",
  "categoryId": 1,
  "tagsNames": ["adventure", "drama"]
}
```

Or should I allow, as an option, to reference the category by name and tags by ids:

```
{
  "title": "Some title",
  "content": "Some content",
  "categoryName": "books",
  "tagsIds": [1, 2]
}
```

To not have different endpoints I could use the following:

```
{
  "title": "Some title",
  "content": "Some content",
  "category": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": null
  },
  "tags": [
    {
      "id": null,
      "name": "adventure"
    },
    {
      "id": null,
      "name": "drama"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then the backend determines how category and tags are referenced: by id or name.

Is there a standard for this?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a standard for this?

Well, there's no standard for that. Pick the approach that makes more sense to your API and ensure it's property documented.

But once you are representing a relationship, it makes sense to use ids. If the names are unique (and they won't change) they could be used to identify your resources.

Answer (score 0):

How category and tags are referenced depends on the model relationships between the option , category and tags . For example

If the model relationship like below :

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

The json could use the following, note : you should make the id of tag be nullable like this `public int? TagId { get; set;}`

```
{
"title": "Some title",
"content": "Some content",
"category": {
"id": 1,
"name": null
},
"tags": [
{
  "id": null,
  "name": "adventure"
},
{
  "id": null,
  "name": "drama"
}
]
}
```

If the model relationship like below :

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public List<string> TagsNames { get; set; }
}
```

The json you may write like below :

```
{
"title": "Some title",
"content": "Some content",
"categoryId": 1,
"tagsNames": ["adventure", "drama"]
}
```